# Unable to load a null value to a DateTime property with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am fetching data from Database and using it as datasource for `Repeater` Some times I have null value for date.

```
var mQuery = (from rmm in db.global_rawmaterial_mains
              where //bla bla bla 
              orderby rmm.name
              select new
              {
                  rmm.name, 
                  rmm.source,
                  date = rmm.global_rawmaterial_entries
                            .Where(p => p.date <= selectedDate)
                            .OrderByDescending(p => p.date)
                            .Select(p => (DateTime?)p.date) // here this date I want to convert .ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
              });
```

The date I see is as follows: `2/9/2009 12:00:00 AM`. In the above query how can I convert it `.ToString();` As I cannot use it as:

```
.Select(p => (DateTime?)p.date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")) //Cannot cast expression of type string to DateTime
```

I cannot use:

```
 .Select(p => (string?)p.date.ToString())// Only non-nullable value type could be underlying of 'System.Nullable'
```

If I try it as:

```
.Select(p =>p.date.ToString())
```

I get the error:

```
Exception: The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.DateTime which is a non-nullable value type.
```

Comment: Why are you trying to cast it to DateTime? if you want it to be a String? Just remove the cast?

Comment: Because when I have null value for Datetime then I get an error `Exception: The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.DateTime which is a non-nullable value type.`

Comment: Try `.Select(p => p.date.ToString())` (what you tried but without the attempt to cast to an instance of `Nullable<>`)

Comment: @KnowledgeOverflow, I didn't mean you should remove the questionmark to make it "not-nullable" I meant you should not cast it at all.

Comment: If you are allowing nulls in the database, then your property/variable should be of a nullable DateTime. (`DateTime?`)

Comment: The error is *very* clear - you can't assign a null to a non-nullable type like DateTime. The solution is to use a *nullable* type for your *entity's property*, ie `DateTime?`. Converting to string just ensures the next bug will have to do with invalid date string formats

Comment: How should VS know which part of the statement should be converted to DateTime? You should be sure to use correct brackets. `.Select(p => p.date.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))`

Comment: @SebastianSchulz what is the point of converting `0001-01-01` to a string?

Comment: Check for null in the Where statement then? .Where(p => p.date != null && p.date <= selectedDate)

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos then what should be the result of converting null to string?

Comment: If you are performing a database query, then converting to string should not be done **at this stage**. Rather you should return a DateTime or DateTime? and then you can either format this as you reference it, or do another linq query (which will be Linq To Objects)

Comment: @sgmoore I am also thinking the same. I thought there would be some other solution that's why I put my question here.

Comment: @SebastianSchulz the conversion to string was the (wrong) attempt to load a null value. The OP doesn't actually want to convert anything to string

Comment: @KnowledgeOverflow people have already answered: use the proper type instead of trying to cast. This *is* covered in all tutorials. Your entity's property should be `DateTime?`, not `DateTime`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am actually using `linq to sql navigation properties`. The `name` and `source` I am selecting from `global_rawmaterial_mains` And `date` from `global_rawmaterial_entries`. So in my case the name and source exist but the record is not found for `p.date <= selectedDate`

Answer (score 0):

```
date = rmm.global_rawmaterial_entries
                            .Where(p => p.date <= selectedDate)
                            .OrderByDescending(p => p.date)
                            .Select(p => p.date)
.Select(d=>d.ToString());
```